# T-SQL cannot delete temp table in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've read other posts on deletion of temp table issues, and none seem to match this particular scenario.

The stored procedure below works, BUT

```
Exec RefreshCustShip
```

generates a lot of errors:

> Can't drop table #tempxxx, because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

How would it not exist? I'm going it on `@@RowCount > 0`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RefreshCustShip]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DELETE FROM CustShip

    DECLARE @CustNo    VARCHAR(255),
            @ShipToIds VARCHAR(255),
            @val VARCHAR(255),
            @Str VARCHAR(255),
            @x   VARCHAR(255)

    DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD /* read only, forward only */ FOR
        SELECT A#Cust#No, SHIP#TO#IDS
        FROM dbo.Cust
        --ORDER BY ModelID

    OPEN C

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @CustNo, @ShipToIds;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- do work here BEGIN CODE BLOCK
        SELECT @ShipToIds = RIGHT(@ShipToIds, Len(@ShipToIds) - 1);

        WHILE LEN( @ShipToIds ) > 0 
        BEGIN 
           IF CHARINDEX( '~', @ShipToIds ) > 0 
               SELECT @val = LEFT( @ShipToIds, CHARINDEX( '~', @ShipToIds )  - 1 ) ,
                      @ShipToIds = RIGHT( @ShipToIds, LEN( @ShipToIds ) - CHARINDEX( '~', @ShipToIds ) ) 
           ELSE 
               SELECT @val = @ShipToIds, @ShipToIds = SPACE(0);

           SELECT @str = 'Select * into #tempxxx from ShipTo where A#CUST#NO = ' + '''' + @CustNo + '''' + 'AND SHIP#TO#ID = ' + '''' + @val + ''''

           EXEC(@str)

           IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
           BEGIN
               SELECT Str = 'INSERT CustShip VALUES (' + '''' + @CustNo + '''' +  ', ' + '''' + @val + '''' + ',1)';
               EXEC(@Str);

               DROP TABLE #tempxxx         /* PROBLEM */  /* !!!!!!!!! */
           END
        END

        -- do work here END CODE BLOCK

        FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @CustNo, @ShipToIds;
    END

    CLOSE C;
    DEALLOCATE C;
END
```

Comment: The temp table should be created with an insert into even if there were 0 records selected.  One thing I don't know, creating a temp table with EXEC, does that create it in the same session as the drop table?  I expect it would but not sure.

Comment: Why are using dynamic sql in the first place? Why are you using a cursor here? This whole things needs a complete rewrite into a set based process.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree. The first thing that needs done is fixing the SHIP#TO#IDS to be a separate table instead of a ~ delimited list.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean and perhaps column names that don't have special characters. ;)

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah, it took me a minute of thinking if that was some sort of alternate alias for doing a dot (.) notation before realizing what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a # table with EXEC and see it outside that EXEC. # tables are scoped to the current session.

Run this example:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200)='CREATE TABLE #TEST(ID INT); INSERT INTO #Test(ID) SELECT 1; SELECT * FROM #TEST;'
EXEC(@String)

SELECT * FROM #TEST
```

The SELECT works inside the EXEC statement but errors when ran outside. If you need the table outside the session, use a ## table.

This would be a decent replacement for the code inside the cursor and avoid the issues you are encountering.

```
    SELECT @ShipToIds = RIGHT(@ShipToIds, Len(@ShipToIds) - 1);

    WHILE LEN( @ShipToIds ) > 0 
    BEGIN 
       IF CHARINDEX( '~', @ShipToIds ) > 0 
           SELECT @val = LEFT( @ShipToIds, CHARINDEX( '~', @ShipToIds )  - 1 ) ,
                  @ShipToIds = RIGHT( @ShipToIds, LEN( @ShipToIds ) - CHARINDEX( '~', @ShipToIds ) ) 
       ELSE 
           SELECT @val = @ShipToIds, @ShipToIds = SPACE(0);

       IF EXISTS(Select * from ShipTo where A#CUST#NO = @CustNo AND SHIP#TO#ID = @val)
       BEGIN
           INSERT INTO CustShip VALUES (@CustNo,@val,1);
       END
    END
```